# passing values from django to google charts DataTable

Tags: javascript, python, django

I'm trying to pass a variable from my django view to javascript as a 2d array so I can populate a google charts DataTable.

can someone please explain why this works:

```
var data=new google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([[1,2,3],
                                                    [4,5,6]])
```

but this does not:

```
foo = [[1,2,3], [4,5,6]]
foo = json.dumps(foo) # the foo stuff is in the django view. i'm just trying to be clear as to what foo is.

var data=new google.visualization.arrayToDataTable({{ foo|safe }})# i've tried this with quotes and without safe. both as json and not.
```

I've tried:

```
foo = [json.dumps(i) for i in foo]
```

I've tried no json at all. I've tried passing numpy arrays, tuples. I've tried to populate the DateTable using `data.addRows` and I've tried iterating through and using `data.addRow`. Along with 100 other things...

I'm obviously missing something important because nothing I'm doing works.

Why when I hard code the data for the DataTable does it work but when I try to pass that same data from my django view it fails??

Any help would be appreciated because I'm about out of blue google links...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on my experience, an example like below should work

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  google.load("visualization", "1", {packages:["corechart"]});
  google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
  function drawChart() {
    var djangodata = {{djangodict|safe}};
    var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable();
    var options = {
        title: 'My Daily Activities'
        };
    var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('piechart'));
    chart.draw(data, options);
  }
```

In your view I suppose you can write something like; below

```
dictdata=[
    ['Task', 'Hours per Day'],
    ['Work',     11],
    ['Eat',      2],
    ['Commute',  2],
    ['Watch TV', 2],
    ['Sleep',    7]
    ]
return render_to_response{template,
                         'djangodict': json.dumps(dictdata),
                         .... other variables here
                         }
```

this should work fine if you are in the process of creating a template on its own for this chart. However declaring django variable as shown above in the script is very important.

```
var djangodata = {{djangodict|safe}};
```

Things might not work at all if you don't :-(

What I did was lil different to the above solution though. I actually created a templatetag to pass data variable to the above javascript and let it draw the chart as I wanted.
Simply because I wanted to include my charts on the dashboard page which that way works fine!